# Pegar valor do Range button e executar função em tempo real

Tags: javascript, html, input, radiobutton, range

Preciso que em `javascript` puro e em tempo real o mesmo valor seja pego e dependendo dele (se for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) somente a div correspondente apareça!

```js
var inputvar = document.getElementById("numerodemqs_input"),
  number_mqs = document.getElementById("resultado1");
inputvar.addEventListener("input", function() {
  number_mqs.innerHTML = inputvar.value;
}, false);

/* Para deixar algo invisível */
function displayNone(NoneId) {
    document.getElementById(NoneId).style.display = "none";
  }
  /* Para deixar algo visível */

function displayBlock(BlockId) {
  document.getElementById(BlockId).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
 <h4>Quantas Media Queries o Header Est&aacute;tico possui?</h4>
<input id="numerodemqs_input" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="">
<h5 id="resultado1"></h5>
<div id="1">
  <h4>Este é para o 1.</h4>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <h4>Este é para o 2.</h4>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <h4>Este é para o 3.</h4>
</div>
<div id="4">
  <h4>Este é para o 4.</h4>
</div>
<div id="5">
  <h4>Este é para o 5.</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterei um pouquinho a logica do seu script, trabalhando com `name` para pegar os elementos que fazem parte do seu conjunto, e atribuindo uma `data-*` para armazenar o valor da `div`.

### Solução 1:

```js
var inputvar = document.getElementById("numerodemqs_input"),
number_mqs = document.getElementById("resultado1");

inputvar.addEventListener("input", function() {
  number_mqs.innerHTML = inputvar.value;
  /* Linha 1 */ var elementos = document.getElementsByName("div");
  /* Linha 2 */ for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    /* Linha 3 */ value_element = elementos[i].getAttribute('data-value');
    /* Linha 4 */ if (value_element == inputvar.value) {
      displayBlock(elementos[i]);
    } else {
      displayNone(elementos[i]);
    }
  }
}, false);

/* Para deixar algo invisível */
function displayNone(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
  /* Para deixar algo visível */

function displayBlock(element) {
  element.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<h4>Quantas Media Queries o Header Est&aacute;tico possui?</h4>
<input id="numerodemqs_input" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="">
<h5 id="resultado1"></h5>
<div name="div" data-value="1">
  <h4>Este é para o 1.</h4>
</div>
<div name="div" data-value="2">
  <h4>Este é para o 2.</h4>
</div>
<div name="div" data-value="3">
  <h4>Este é para o 3.</h4>
</div>
<div name="div" data-value="4">
  <h4>Este é para o 4.</h4>
</div>
<div name="div" data-value="5">
  <h4>Este é para o 5.</h4>
</div>
```

Explicação do código acima:

> Linha 1: Pego todos os elementos* dentro do formulário que possuem
>   determinado `name` que eu definir, no caso `div`, e jogo dentro de um
>   `array`;
>
> Linha 2: Executo um `for` pra iterar em cima de cada elemento dentro
>   do `array`, `elementos.length` me diz a quantidade de elementos que o
>   `array` possui;
>
> Linha 3: Pego o valor que esta dentro do atributo `data-value` do
>   elemento;
>
> Linha 4: Verifico se o valor do elemento `input` é o mesmo valor do
>   elemento do laco atual, se for, é porque o elemento deve ser exibido,
>   então mando a referencia dele para sua função, se não for, é porque
>   não deve ser exibido;
>
> *Obs: Note que estou pegando a referencia do elemento, e não o `id`, ou outro atributo, assim fica mais fácil altera-lo caso seja
>   necessário.

Lembrando que os atributos do tipo `data-*` são uma implementação nova do `html5`, então para alguns navegadores mais antigos, ou dispositivos mobile possa não ter suporte, [veja uma lista mais completa aqui](http://caniuse.com/#search=data-*), talvez uma melhor solução (cross-browsing) fosse um mix do que foi feito, so que pegando o `id` dos elementos pelo atributo `name` e com o `id` bloquear ou não a visualização.

---

### Solução 2:

```js
var inputvar = document.getElementById("numerodemqs_input"),
number_mqs = document.getElementById("resultado1");

inputvar.addEventListener("input", function() {
  number_mqs.innerHTML = inputvar.value;
  var elementos = document.getElementsByName("div");
  for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    value_element = elementos[i].getAttribute('id');
    if (value_element == inputvar.value) {
      displayBlock(elementos[i]);
    } else {
      displayNone(elementos[i]);
    }
  }
}, false);

/* Para deixar algo invisível */
function displayNone(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
  /* Para deixar algo visível */

function displayBlock(element) {
  element.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<h4>Quantas Media Queries o Header Est&aacute;tico possui?</h4>
<input id="numerodemqs_input" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="">
<h5 id="resultado1"></h5>
<div id="1" name="div">
  <h4>Este é para o 1.</h4>
</div>
<div id="2" name="div">
  <h4>Este é para o 2.</h4>
</div>
<div id="3" name="div">
  <h4>Este é para o 3.</h4>
</div>
<div id="4" name="div">
  <h4>Este é para o 4.</h4>
</div>
<div id="5" name="div">
  <h4>Este é para o 5.</h4>
</div>
```

Explicação do código acima:

O código é similar ao anterior com exceção no atributo que usa para referenciar o elemento correto, em vez de usar um atributo do tipo `data-*`, eu uso o `id`.

Comment: Muito obrigado marcelo! Salvou demais, haha Teria como explicar um pouco aquele elementos.length? Valeuu

Comment: o atributo `name` serve para localizar ancoras, o atributo certo a ser usado neste caso seria uma `class` seguido de `querySelectorAll()` (ou `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: @MoshMage note que no meu exemplo uso o `name` somente para localizar e pegar a referencia dos elementos que irei trabalhar, não existe uma norma para como se trabalhar nesses casos :)